# Salvar Json em um banco de dados mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

Não estou sabendo fazer o processo para salvar um *JSON* dentro do banco de dados. O processo todo está sendo assim:

Estou enviando de um outro servidor através do script abaixo:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * from mgs_castloang";
 $Ds_Retorno = ibase_query($sql);


$count = 0;
while ($row[$count] = ibase_fetch_assoc($Ds_Retorno)){
    $count++;
}

$json =  json_encode($row);


$ch = curl_init('http://api.dominio.com.br/megs.php');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Depois que ele executa esse processo, tem o script que está esperando esse *JSON*:

```
<?php
include_once "conexao.php";



$n                      = $_POST ["NUMERO"];  
$tipo               = $_POST ["TIPO"]; 
$valor               = $_POST ["VALOR"];  
$status              = $_POST ["STATUS"]; 
$venc                 = $_POST ["VENC"];  

//Inserindo no banco
$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO gr_api (NUMERO, TIPO,VALOR,STATUS, VENC  ) 
VALUES ('$n', '$tipo', '$valor', '$status', '$venc')");
```

Só que nada salva no banco de dados. A conexão funciona perfeitamente, mas não sei se o *JSON* não chega na *API* ou a forma de salvar os dados no banco de dados estão incorretas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está enviando um JSON, não é possível capturar os valores com `$_POST`. Este serve apenas para requisições do tipo `x-www-form-urlencoded` e `multipart/form-data`.

Para capturar o JSON enviando, você pode utilizar `file_get_contents` ou `fgets`, por exemplo:

**file_get_contents:**

```
<?php

    include_once "conexao.php";

    $json = json_decode( trim(file_get_contents('php://input')) );
```

- O `file_get_contents('php://input')` irá pegar todos os dados de entrada (enviados da requisição)
- `trim` irá apagar os espaços do início e final do JSON

**fgets:**

```
<?php

    include_once "conexao.php";

    $json = json_decode( trim(fgets(STDIN)) );
```

- `STDIN` é uma constante que irá indicar o caminho para o PHP ler os dados de entrada (normalmente `php://stdin`).
- `fgets` irá ler o conteúdo desse valor de entrada.

---

Para capturar os valores do JSON (após feito um dos passos acima), irá depender da estrutura do JSON. Você poderá fazer:

```
$json->NUMERO;
$json->TIPO;
```

Ou ainda

```
foreach($json as $key => $value) {
    echo "{$value}", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Só pra constar, pelo código `while ($row[$count] = ibase_fetch_assoc($Ds_Retorno)){
    $count++;
}

$json =  json_encode($row);` creio que sera mesmo um array, logo terá que iterar e então dentro do foreach sim irá pegar `foreach ($json as $value) { $value->NUMERO }` e será um INSERT por loop, por exemplo.

Comment: Valeu Galera!!
Guilherme, uma dúvida. Dentro do foreach tenho que colocar também o INSERT ?

Comment: Acho que ainda estou fazendo algo errado. Podem me ajudar ? os dados não vão para o banco. Eu preciso que seja salvo em loop. Pois o JSON vem com vários registros.

Desde já sou muito grato na ajuda.

<?php
include_once "conexao.php";

$json = json_decode( trim(file_get_contents('php://input')) );

foreach ($json as $value) { $value->NUMERO; }


$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO gr_api (NUMERO, TIPO,VALOR,STATUS, VENC) 
VALUES ('$value->NUMERO', '$value->TIPO', '$value->VALOR', '$value->STATUS', '$value->VENC')");

Comment: @RobsonFreitas Dê um `var_dump($json);` para verificarmos quais dados o API está recebendo, sem saber a estrutura do JSON, fica difícil.